# SQL error or missing database (near “?”: syntax error)

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite, prepared-statement, placeholder

```
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SONG_DETAILS + " WHERE " + TABLE_SONG_DETAILS + "." + "artist" + "=? ORDER BY track ?";
private PreparedStatement queryAllSongsInfo = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);

// the user inputs the artist_name and ORDER
queryAllSongsInfo.setString(1, artist_name);
if (order == ORDER_BY_DESC) {
    queryAllSongsInfo.setString(2, "DESC");
} else {
    queryAllSongsInfo.setString(2, "ASC");
}
```

Shows the error: SQL error or missing database `(near “?”: syntax error)`
If i only include the first placeholder then it works fine.

```
queryAllSongsInfo.setString(1, artist_name);
```

Why cant i use multiple placeholders ?? Why the second placeholder doesn't consider the second input from user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placeholders only for column values. You can't use them for table names, column names or (as you tried in this example) reserved words.

You can create two SQL strings, one for ascending order and the other for descending order:

```
private static final String QUERY_ASC = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_SONG_DETAILS +" WHERE "+TABLE_SONG_DETAILS+"."+"artist"+"=? ORDER BY track ASC";
private static final String QUERY_DESC = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_SONG_DETAILS +" WHERE "+TABLE_SONG_DETAILS+"."+"artist"+"=? ORDER BY track DESC";

private PreparedStatement queryAllSongsInfo = conn.prepareStatement(order==ORDER_BY_DESC?QUERY_DESC:QUERY_ASC);

// the user inputs the artist_name and ORDER
queryAllSongsInfo.setString(1, artist_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

No when you use :

```
queryAllSongsInfo.setString(2, "DESC");
```

This will put `DESC` or `ASC` keywords between two quotes like this `ORDER BY track 'DESC'` and this is not correct.

Instead use concatenation directly with the query for example :

```
String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_SONG_DETAILS +" WHERE "+TABLE_SONG_DETAILS+"."+"artist"+"=? ORDER BY track ";
if(order==ORDER_BY_DESC) {
    QUERY += "DESC";
}else {
    QUERY += "ASC";
}
PreparedStatement queryAllSongsInfo = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
queryAllSongsInfo.setString(1, artist_name);
```